# Is there an algorithm for calculating the multiplicative order of x modulo y (for y < 1000) that doesn't require a BigInteger type?

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

The algorithm I'm using at the moment runs into extremely high numbers very quickly.  A step in the algorithm I'm to raises **x** to the result of the totient function applied to **y**.  The result is that you can run into very large numbers.

Eg.  When calculating the [multiplicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of 10 modulo 53:

```
10^totient(53) == 10^52 == 1 * 10^52
```

The following algorithm fares a bit better either in terms of avoiding large numbers, but it still fails where **10^mOrder** is greater than the capacity of the data type:

```
  mOrder = 1
  while 10^mOrder % 53 != 1
      if mOrder >= i
          mOrder = 0;
          break
      else
          mOrder = mOrder + 1
```

Comment: Not part of the original question but a neat way to combine the answers from @schnaader and @Svante. The multiplicative order you're looking for must divide totient(c), so you don't have to test every a^b. If you enumerate the divisors of totient(c) you can use @schnaader's method to do the exponentiations, and @Svante's method to use already-computed results to calculate others - i.e 10^1, 10^2 (by squaring), 10^4 (by squaring), 10^13 = (10^4)^3 * (10^1), 10^26 (by squaring). (If it's none of those, it must be 52).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Modular exponentiation, it is possible to calculate (10 ^ mOrder % 53) or in general, any (a ^ b mod c) without getting values much bigger than c. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) for details, there's this sample code, too:

```
Bignum modpow(Bignum base, Bignum exponent, Bignum modulus) {

    Bignum result = 1;

    while (exponent > 0) {
        if ((exponent & 1) == 1) {
            // multiply in this bit's contribution while using modulus to keep result small
            result = (result * base) % modulus;
        }
        // move to the next bit of the exponent, square (and mod) the base accordingly
        exponent >>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about this especially considering I used it two days ago.  I reckon I need some coffee.

Comment: Or perhaps some sleep and a coffee afterwards ;)

Answer (score 6):

Why exponentiate?  Can't you just multiply modulo *n* in a loop?

```
(defun multiplicative-order (a n)
  (if (> (gcd a n) 1)
      0
      (do ((order 1 (+ order 1))
           (mod-exp (mod a n) (mod (* mod-exp a) n)))
          ((= mod-exp 1) order))))
```

Or, in ptheudo (sic) code:

```
def multiplicative_order (a, n) :
    if gcd (a, n) > 1 :
        return 0
      else:
        order = 1
        mod_exp = a mod n
        while mod_exp != 1 :
            order += 1
            mod_exp = (mod_exp * a) mod n
        return order
```

Comment: Have you checked the code for a = 49 and n = 3? I get 2, but [it should be 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MultiplicativeOrder%5B49,3%5D). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're right, there was a bug.  Fixed: need to do modulus on initial value too.

Comment: Also, this should not return 0 if the arguments are not coprime, but signal an error.